# Survey site in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site, survey-list, survey

I need to create a site in SharePoint,where users can login there with their Active directory credentials,create their own survey site and circulate among their teams.Is there is any possible way for this ?
Looking for valuable replies.
~Ram

Comment: how many users we are talking about, do you want user a can manage User B survey?